# Where is Rotharr Hatherhand?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, content-identification, princes-of-the-apocalypse

In the campaign Princes of the Apocalypse, on p.156 the group encounters

> a boy named Braelen Hatherhand who names his father as a member of the Believers.

Since my group hadn't encountered this person, they asked who he was and where they could find him. I cannot find this guy in Red Larch, and skimming through the other chapters, his name hasn't jumped out at me.

Where can I find his location in the book / campaign?

Comment: Just a note, the fathers name is spelled Rothar, I am not certain and can no longer find the proper supporting documents but I believe Rothar Hatherhand and his sun Braelen show up in some of the DDEN -01 through ??? Adventure League modules that were run during the Princes of the Apocalypse 'Season' for D&D Adventurers League; not to be confused with the actual Princes of the Apocalypse D&D Encounters adventure.  The Adventurer League modules all vaguely connect to the over arching story, and I remember one revolving around Red Larch.

Comment: @Airatome If you can find those sources, I think you'd have the answer. An exhaustive search of *Princes of the Apocalypse* shows that Rotharr is not mentioned anywhere else in the book.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie what about "Rothar" (one R at the end), which Airatome provided as the correct spelling?

Comment: @doppelgreener Right! Yes, the post has it right now, with an *o* and two *r*s.

Answer (score 2):

I believe he is not listed in the notes because he is a "DM's Choice" NPC. Basically he is somewhere around Red Larch, and can be found fairly easily by asking around. Not to mention the son would certainly know where his father lives (and could likely lead you to his own home).

I expect this was left out mostly as flavor text that a creative DM could add in.

Source: [*Princes of the Apocalypse*, Chapter 6](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/pota/alarums-and-excursions#T4Antechamber)

> The Believers area secret group made up of some of the most important people in town of Red Larch. Braelen tells you that Rotharr Hatherhand (his father), ... are the Believers that he knows.

So he's obviously a member of that group, and someone important in the town (I believe he is a town council member). With this information, he should be able to be found easily simply by asking townsfolk. Being a council member he is likely at the town hall, or moving around the town somewhere.

**Note**: It should be mentioned that based on other information in-game, the town council is not meeting currently. So there is always the chance they are in hiding/etc (e.g. not meant to be found).